# How to translate one column in SQL with a given condition

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm fairly new to SQL and have an exercise I'm trying to figure out how to translate a **YEAR** column into the following conditions:

YEAR is 1 if student is registered in courses 1009 & 1029
YEAR is 2 if student has completed courses 1009 & 1029 but is registered in 2011 & 2021
YEAR is 3 if student has completed courses 1009 & 1029 and 2011 & 2021

Here are the tables:

TABLE_A has the current term and TABLE_B has all the past terms and present terms and classes a student has taken/is taking.

**TABLE_A:**

| TERM | ID | LAST_NAME | FIRST_NAME | DEGREE | COURSE | COURSE_CODE | CREDIT | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024 | 0011 | Richards | Diana | PHD | 3000 | 030011 | S | N |
| 2024 | 0011 | Richards | Diana | PHD | 3011 | 030111 | S | N |
| 2024 | 0011 | Richards | Diana | PHD | 3015 | 030015 | S | N |
| 2024 | 0012 | Smith | Alex | PHD | 2011 | 020012 | S | N |
| 2024 | 0012 | Smith | Alex | PHD | 2001 | 020013 | S | N |
| 2024 | 0012 | Smith | Alex | PHD | 2021 | 020014 | S | N |
| 2024 | 0012 | Smith | Alex | PHD | 2023 | 020015 | S | N |
| 2024 | 0013 | Thompson | Robert | PHD | 1009 | 010011 | S | N |
| 2024 | 0013 | Thompson | Robert | PHD | 1029 | 010020 | S | N |

**TABLE_B:**

| TERM_YEAR | STUDENT_ID | CLASS_CODE | CLASS | CLASS_MARK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 0012 | 010011 | 1001 | A |
| 2020 | 0011 | 010021 | 1009 |  |
| 2021 | 0011 | 010020 | 1029 | B+ |
| 2021 | 0012 | 010001 | 1011 | B |
| 2022 | 0011 | 020012 | 2011 | C+ |
| 2022 | 0012 | 010021 | 1009 | A- |
| 2022 | 0012 | 010020 | 1029 | A |
| 2023 | 0011 | 020014 | 2021 | A+ |
| 2024 | 0012 | 020012 | 2011 |  |
| 2024 | 0012 | 020013 | 2001 |  |
| 2024 | 0012 | 020014 | 2021 |  |
| 2024 | 0012 | 020015 | 2023 |  |
| 2024 | 0013 | 010011 | 1009 |  |
| 2024 | 0013 | 010020 | 1029 |  |

The expected result should be:

| YEAR | ID | LAST_NAME | FIRST_NAME | DEGREE | CREDIT | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024 | 0011 | Richards | Diana | PHD | S | 3 |
| 2024 | 0012 | Smith | Alex | PHD | S | 2 |
| 2024 | 0013 | Thompson | Robert | PHD | S | 1 |

How should I go about checking both tables and translating the year column to the appropriate years?

TIA!

I have tried this so far but still need to check from TABLE_B:

select distinct year, id, last_name, first_name, degree, credit,
coalesce(
MAX(case when course IN ('1009', '1029) then '01' end),
MAX(case when course IN ('1009', '1029) AND course IN ('2011', '2021) then '02' end),
MAX(case when course IN (('1009', '1029) AND course IN ('2011', '2021)) end) as year
from TABLE_A

Comment: For what it's worth, some of this complexity is because your data model is a bit wonky. If you can change it, that'd be a good idea. Otherwise, play the hand you are dealt. Table_A (Student) should ideally only have data directly related to the human student, rather than a hodgepodge with course information mixed in. Then your course table can contain all the information on the course and result.

Comment: Learning database design is a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certainly ways to write this more concisely, without the redundancy, but when rules get complex I'm partial to breaking them up so clear names can be given. That way the query reads more like natural language.

**Assumptions:**

1.) Table_A will always have only the current term (2024). Logic will still work otherwise, but the DISTINCT() might need fiddled with.

2.) Table_A.credit will always be the same per student year. Gist would still work otherwise, but plain old DISTINCT() won't.

3.) Grade is not considered for completion. Just that the course has been taken. Edited on clarification in comments.

**Rationale :** ClassMarks contains all the data you need to assign the rules. So get the lastest year they were enrolled in each class, latest year they completed each class, then once that is at Student grain you can simply join and derive the rule based on whatever the Student.Term_Year is at a given point.

**Query:**

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/dlOUH62S

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Students (
    TERM INT,
    ID INT,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    DEGREE VARCHAR(50),
    COURSE INT,
    COURSE_CODE VARCHAR(50),
    CREDIT VARCHAR(1),
    YEAR VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO Students (TERM, ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, DEGREE, COURSE, COURSE_CODE, CREDIT, YEAR) VALUES
(2024, 0011, 'Richards', 'Diana', 'PHD', 3000, '030011', 'S', 'N'),
(2024, 0011, 'Richards', 'Diana', 'PHD', 3011, '030111', 'S', 'N'),
(2024, 0011, 'Richards', 'Diana', 'PHD', 3015, '030015', 'S', 'N'),
(2024, 0012, 'Smith', 'Alex', 'PHD', 2011, '020012', 'S', 'N'),
(2024, 0012, 'Smith', 'Alex', 'PHD', 2001, '020013', 'S', 'N'),
(2024, 0012, 'Smith', 'Alex', 'PHD', 2021, '020014', 'S', 'N'),
(2024, 0012, 'Smith', 'Alex', 'PHD', 2023, '020015', 'S', 'N'),
(2024, 0013, 'Thompson', 'Robert', 'PHD', 1009, '010011', 'S', 'N'),
(2024, 0013, 'Thompson', 'Robert', 'PHD', 1029, '010020', 'S', 'N');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ClassMarks (
    TERM_YEAR INT,
    STUDENT_ID INT,
    CLASS_CODE VARCHAR(50),
    CLASS VARCHAR(255),
    CLASS_MARK VARCHAR(2)
);

    INSERT INTO ClassMarks (TERM_YEAR, STUDENT_ID, CLASS_CODE, CLASS, CLASS_MARK) VALUES
    (2020, 0012, '010011', '1001', 'A'),
    (2020, 0011, '010021', '1009', ''),
    (2021, 0011, '010020', '1029', 'B+'),
    (2021, 0012, '010001', '1011', 'B'),
    (2022, 0011, '020012', '2011', 'C+'),
    (2022, 0012, '010021', '1009', 'A-'),
    (2022, 0012, '010020', '1029', 'A'),
    (2023, 0011, '020014', '2021', 'A+'),
    (2024, 0012, '020012', '2011', ''),
    (2024, 0012, '020013', '2001', ''),
    (2024, 0012, '020014', '2021', ''),
    (2024, 0012, '020015', '2023', ''),
    (2024, 0013, '010011', '1009', ''),
    (2024, 0013, '010020', '1029', '');


with year_rules as (
    select Student_ID,
           max(case when class = 1009 then term_year end) as latest_enrollment_in_1009,
           max(case when class = 1029 then term_year end) as latest_enrollment_in_1029,
           max(case when class = 2011 then term_year end) as latest_enrollment_in_2011,
           max(case when class = 2021 then term_year end) as latest_enrollment_in_2021
      from ClassMarks
     group
        by Student_ID)
select distinct
       s.term,
       s.id,
       s.last_name,
       s.first_name,
       s.degree,
       s.credit,
       case when latest_enrollment_in_1009 = s.term
             and latest_enrollment_in_1029 = s.term then 1
            when latest_enrollment_in_2011 = s.term 
             and latest_enrollment_in_2021 = s.term then 2
            when greatest(latest_enrollment_in_1009, 
                          latest_enrollment_in_1029,
                          latest_enrollment_in_2011,
                          latest_enrollment_in_2021) < s.term then 3
         end as derived_year
  from Students s
 inner
  join year_rules yr
    on s.id = yr.student_id;
```

Comment: What if a student has a record of taking the required course in the past year, however there is no class_mark recorded?

Comment: @HaileyGomez Can you point to the record in your sample data which illustrates that case? If there is not one currently, can you add it and I'll update the query to handle it.

Comment: I edited TABLE_B with student 0011 as an example. He has already taken 1009 but has no grade recorded.

Comment: @HalleyGomez So what should student 0011 year be in that case? That falls out of the bounds of the rules you've mentioned. Since they aren't currently enrolled in year 1 classes, but have not completed both either. Or is it just enough that they've taken the course, regardless of their mark?

Comment: Yeah regardless of their mark, as long as they've taken the course

Comment: @HaileyGomez That actually simplifies things a good deal. Edited with updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first take a look at **database normalization**. TABLE_A has repeating data that should be transformed in its own table `student` and others:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
    ,name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO student (id,name) VALUES
(1,'Diana Richards')
,(2,'Alex Smith')
,(3,'Robert Thompson')
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS course (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
    ,name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO course (id,name) VALUES
(1,'1009')
,(2,'1029')
,(3,'2011')
,(4,'2021')
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grade (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
    ,name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO grade (id,name) VALUES
(1,'A+')
,(2,'A')
,(3,'A-')
,(4,'B+')
,(5,'B')
,(6,'B-')
,(7,'C+')
,(8,'C')
,(9,'C-')
/*...*/
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student_and_course (
    year YEAR
    ,student BIGINT UNSIGNED
    ,course BIGINT UNSIGNED
    ,grade BIGINT UNSIGNED
    ,PRIMARY KEY (year,student,course)
    ,FOREIGN KEY (student)
        REFERENCES student (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
    ,FOREIGN KEY (course)
        REFERENCES course (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
    ,FOREIGN KEY (grade)
        REFERENCES grade (id)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO student_and_course (year,student,course,grade) VALUES
(2020,2,1,2)
,(2020,1,1,6)
,(2021,1,2,4)
,(2021,2,1,5)
,(2022,1,3,7)
,(2022,2,1,3)
,(2022,2,2,2)
,(2023,1,4,1)
,(2024,2,3,NULL)
,(2024,2,3,NULL)
,(2024,3,1,NULL)
,(2024,3,2,NULL)
;
```

To select the ones in 3rd year should be:

```sql
SELECT
  student_and_course.year
  ,student.name
FROM
  student_and_course
  LEFT JOIN student ON student.id = student_and_course.student
WHERE
  student_and_course.course IN (3,4)
  AND student_and_course.grade IS NOT NULL
  AND student_and_course.grade <= 9
;
```

Answer (score -4):

the condition is in WHERE in select , from , WHERE

Comment: Hi Raphael, this doesn't quite qualify as an answer. There should be code which addresses the question along with an explanation of how it works.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

As @Error_2646 mentioned, you'll need to include some samples.

Additionally, your answer does not address the question - the question is in fact regarding JOINING tables.